# Fastest way to iterate function over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a function which operates over lines of a csv file, adding values of different cells to dictionaries depending on whether conditions are met:

```py
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in args.csv], ignore_index = True)

ID_Use_Totals = {}
ID_Order_Dates = {}
ID_Received_Dates = {}
ID_Refs = {}
IDs = args.ID

def TSQs(row):

    global ID_Use_Totals, ID_Order_Dates, ID_Received_Dates

    if row['Stock Item'] not in IDs:
        pass
    else:
        if row['Action'] in ['Order/Resupply', 'Cons. Purchase']:
            if row['Stock Item'] not in ID_Order_Dates:
                ID_Order_Dates[row['Stock Item']] = [{row['Ref']: pd.to_datetime(row['TransDate'])}]
            else:
                ID_Order_Dates[row['Stock Item']].append({row['Ref']: pd.to_datetime(row['TransDate'])})
        
        elif row['Action'] == 'Received':
                
             if row['Stock Item'] not in ID_Received_Dates:
                ID_Received_Dates[row['Stock Item']] = [{row['Ref']: pd.to_datetime(row['TransDate'])}]
            else:
                ID_Received_Dates[row['Stock Item']].append({row['Ref']: pd.to_datetime(row['TransDate'])})
                                    
        elif row['Action'] == 'Use':
            if row['Stock Item'] in ID_Use_Totals: 
                ID_Use_Totals[row['Stock Item']].append(row['Qty'])
            else:
                ID_Use_Totals[row['Stock Item']] = [row['Qty']]
                                       
        else:
            pass
```

Currently, I  am doing:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    TSQs(row)
```

But `timer()` returns between 70 and 90 seconds for a 40,000 line csv file.

I want to know what the fastest way of implementing this is over the entire dataframe (which could potentially be hundreds of thousands of rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wager not using Pandas for this could be faster.

Additionally, you can use `defaultdict`s to avoid having to check whether you've seen a given product yet:

```
import csv
import collections
import datetime

ID_Use_Totals = collections.defaultdict(list)
ID_Order_Dates = collections.defaultdict(list)
ID_Received_Dates = collections.defaultdict(list)
ID_Refs = {}
IDs = set(args.ID)
order_actions = {"Order/Resupply", "Cons. Purchase"}

for filename in args.csv:
    with open(filename) as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f):
            item = row["Stock Item"]
            if item not in IDs:
                continue
            ref = row["Ref"]
            action = row["Action"]
            if action in order_actions:
                date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(row["TransDate"])
                ID_Order_Dates[item].append({ref: date})
            elif action == "Received":
                date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(row["TransDate"])
                ID_Received_Dates[item].append({ref: date})
            elif action == "Use":
                ID_Use_Totals[item].append(row["Qty"])
```

**EDIT:** If the CSV is really of the form

```
"Employee", "Stock Location", "Stock Item"
"Ordered", "16", "32142"
```

the stock CSV module can't quite parse it.

You could use Pandas to parse the file, then iterate over rows, though I'm not sure if this'll end up being much faster in the end:

```
import collections
import datetime
import pandas

ID_Use_Totals = collections.defaultdict(list)
ID_Order_Dates = collections.defaultdict(list)
ID_Received_Dates = collections.defaultdict(list)
ID_Refs = {}
IDs = set(args.ID)
order_actions = {"Order/Resupply", "Cons. Purchase"}

for filename in args.csv:
    for index, row in pd.read_csv(filename).iterrows():
        item = row["Stock Item"]
        if item not in IDs:
            continue
        ref = row["Ref"]
        action = row["Action"]
        if action in order_actions:
            date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(row["TransDate"])
            ID_Order_Dates[item].append({ref: date})
        elif action == "Received":
            date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(row["TransDate"])
            ID_Received_Dates[item].append({ref: date})
        elif action == "Use":
            ID_Use_Totals[item].append(row["Qty"])
```

Comment: I'm getting a ````KeyError```` on ````row["Stock Item"]````, printing the first row gives: ````OrderedDict([(None, ['Employee', 'Stock Location', 'Stock Item', 'Supplier', 'TransDate', 'When should the stock team receive this', 'Applied', 'Qty', 'Adjustment', 'UnitPrice', 'Total', 'State', 'Action', 'Ref'])])````

Comment: I think your CSV files may have different separators than the `csv` module defaults, and it's mis-parsing them...

Comment: Do you know of any way to define the separators?

Comment: Yes – you'll need to pass a suitable CSV dialect object to the `csv.DictReader()` constructor (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect). What does the CSV look like, what are the actual separators?

Comment: Opening it in a text file shows that it's in the format ````"Ordered", "16", "32142"```` for example

Comment: It's worth noting though, as a quick google suggests that this is the regular format, that the csv looks 'normal' opening it in a text file, but when I've been using pandas I have had to access the columns with an additional space, e.g. ````row['Stock Item ']````. I didn't put this in the question so as not to confuse people

Comment: Okay, I added an alternate approach that worked for a minimal example file (as I added too).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218895/discussion-between-jonathan-dyke-and-akx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apply function. The code will look like this:

```
df.apply(TSQs, axis=1)
```

Here when `axis=1`, each row will be sent to the function `TSQs` as a `pd.Series` from where you can index like `row["Ref"]` to get value of that line. Since this is a vector operation, it will run so much after that a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Probably fastest not to iterate at all:

```
# Build some boolean indices for your various conditions
idx_stock_item = df["Stock Item"].isin(IDs)
idx_purchases =  df["Action"].isin(['Order/Resupply', 'Cons. Purchase'])
idx_order_dates = df["Stock Item"].isin(ID_Order_Dates)

# combine the indices to act on specific rows all at once
idx_combined = idx_stock_item & idx_purchases & ~idx_order_dates
# It looks like you were putting a single entry dictionary in each row - wouldn't it make sense to rather just use two columns? i.e. take advantage of the DataFrame data structure
ID_Order_Dates.loc[df.loc[idx_combined, "Stock Item"], "Ref"] = df.loc[idx_combined, "Ref"]   
ID_Order_Dates.loc[df.loc[idx_combined, "Stock Item"], "Date"] = df.loc[idx_combined, "TransDate"]

# repeat for your other cases
# ...
```

Comment: I was mainly using dictionaries for easier processing after. I'm getting the order/received dates to calculate the average lead times for different stock items, and then using that alongside the usage rate to get the target stock quantity - I'm not sure exactly what I gain by adding rows to the dataframe, but I am quite new to pandas

Comment: This isn't adding rows, it's just using two columns. i.e. your ref is in one column and your date is in another on the same row. This way you can still easily get both pieces of info for a given row, but it will be much easier to work in pandas.